# custom listof not in content

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

This is the initial part of my thesis:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openright]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{booktabs} % To thicken table lines

%\usepackage[algo2e,ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{morefloats}
%\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}



\newcommand{\todo}[1]{{\color{blue} #1}}


\selectlanguage{english}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{oss}{Observation}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}[section]
\newtheorem{dataset}{Dataset}[section]
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}[section]


\floatstyle{boxed}
\newfloat{Pseudocode}{hbtp}{lop}[section]
\floatname{Pseudocode}{Pseudocode}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}
\DeclareMathOperator\kdist{\mathit{k}-distance}




\title{Computational Intelligence for Data Analysis with OES Data in Semiconductor Manufacturing}
\author{Luca Puggini}
\date{\today}




\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{titlepage}
Luca Puggini


\end{titlepage}

\clearpage

\pagestyle{empty}

\clearpage

\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}



\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Thesis


\tableofcontents                             % indice

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listof{Pseudocode}{List of Pseudocodes}

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


%\begin{titlepage}
%\maketitle
%\end{titlepage}







\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}

%\tableofcontents                             % indice

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\parindent 0pt

\chapter*{Practical Information} 
....
```

Everything works but in my content only `\listoffigures`
`\listoftables` are referenced while 
`\listof{Pseudocode}{List of Pseudocodes}` is not.

How can I add a reference to the `\listof{Pseudocode}{List of Pseudocodes}` in the table of content?

EDIT:
The answer partially works. List of pseudocodes is now in the table of contents but the layout of the list of pseudocodes page is bad and different from the tableoffigure one.

[image]

EDIT 2:
This is an example reproducing the problem:

```
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openright]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{booktabs} % To thicken table lines

%\usepackage[algo2e,ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{morefloats}
%\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}



\newcommand{\todo}[1]{{\color{blue} #1}}


\selectlanguage{english}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{oss}{Observation}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}[section]
\newtheorem{dataset}{Dataset}[section]
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}[section]


\floatstyle{boxed}
\newfloat{Pseudocode}{hbtp}{lop}[section]
\floatname{Pseudocode}{Pseudocode}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}
\DeclareMathOperator\kdist{\mathit{k}-distance}


\newcommand{\listofpseudocodes}{
\tocfile{List of Pseudocodes}{lop}
\listof{Pseudocode}{List of Pseudocodes}
}


\title{Title}
\author{author}
\date{\today}




\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{titlepage}
title 

\end{titlepage}

\clearpage

\pagestyle{empty}

\clearpage

\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}



\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Thesis


\tableofcontents                             % indice

\listoffigures
\listoftables
%\listof{Pseudocode}{List of Pseudocodes}
\listofpseudocodes

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


%\begin{titlepage}
%\maketitle
%\end{titlepage}







\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}

%\tableofcontents                             % indice

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\parindent 0pt

\chapter{Ch 1}

\begin{table}

\caption{table 1 }
\end{table} 


\section{Sec 1}

\chapter{Ch 2}

\begin{Pseudocode}

\caption{pseudocode 1}
\end{Pseudocode}

\begin{table}
\caption{table2}
\end{table}



\begin{Pseudocode}

\caption{pseudocode 2}
\end{Pseudocode}



 \end{document}
```

Comment: `\listof`  by the `float` package is not designed to have a ToC entry.

Comment: How can I emulate the behviour of list of figure for my custom float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\listof` feature by the `float` does not add an entry to the ToC. This can be changed by wrapping a command around this, that automatically adds the contentsline to the ToC`;

```
\newcommand{\listofpseudocodes}{%
\phantomsection
\listof{Pseudocode}{List of Pseudocodes}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Pseudocodes}
}
```

Here's the 'MWE' by the O.P.

```
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openright]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{booktabs} % To thicken table lines

%\usepackage[algo2e,ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{morefloats}
%\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}



\newcommand{\todo}[1]{{\color{blue} #1}}


\selectlanguage{english}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{oss}{Observation}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}[section]
\newtheorem{dataset}{Dataset}[section]
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}[section]


\floatstyle{boxed}
\newfloat{Pseudocode}{hbtp}{lop}[section]
\floatname{Pseudocode}{Pseudocode}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}
\DeclareMathOperator\kdist{\mathit{k}-distance}


\newcommand{\listofpseudocodes}{%
\phantomsection
\listof{Pseudocode}{List of Pseudocodes}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Pseudocodes}
}


\title{Title}
\author{author}
\date{\today}




\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{titlepage}
title 

\end{titlepage}

\clearpage

\pagestyle{empty}

\clearpage

\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}



\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Thesis


\tableofcontents                             % indice

\listoffigures
\listoftables
%\listof{Pseudocode}{List of Pseudocodes}
\listofpseudocodes

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}


%\begin{titlepage}
%\maketitle
%\end{titlepage}







\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}

%\tableofcontents                             % indice

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\parindent 0pt

\chapter{Ch 1}

\begin{table}

\caption{table 1 }
\end{table} 


\section{Sec 1}

\chapter{Ch 2}

\begin{Pseudocode}

\caption{pseudocode 1}
\end{Pseudocode}

\begin{table}
\caption{table2}
\end{table}



\begin{Pseudocode}

\caption{pseudocode 2}
\end{Pseudocode}



 \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks this is almost a solution. Now the list is in the table of content but the List of Pseudocodes page has a terrible layout. It is different from the one in the List of tables page. In addition all the entries are in the same line making it unreadable.

Comment: @Donbeo: Which layout? Your 'fragmented' code has no layout stuff etc. for the Pseudocode list of page ;-) You cannot complain about things in your own code which we are not responsible for.

Comment: I have edited the question. This is how page list of pseudocodes looks now

Comment: @Donbeo: Well, I can't reproduce it here without having code. Try to remove the `\begingroup....\endgroup}` in `\listofpseudocodes`

Comment: It's not working. I'll try to post a full working example.

Comment: Ok I wrote a simple code that reproduces the problem

Comment: @Donbeo: Apparently, `tocfile` screws up the formatting really. I changed the approach, more low-level right now