# How to generate a list of all definitions made in a theorem environment?

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, environments, theorems

I'm currently defining terms in a note-taking document (article class) using

```
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}
```

in the preamble, and defining the terms within

```
\begin{mydef}
\textbf{Term} is ...
\endmydef}
```

I wonder if there's a straightforward way I can create a list of definitions comparable to what is generated by

```
\tableofcontents
```

using a similar, custom command? A contents-style list of all definitions would be helpful, and so would a command which reprints all of the definitions from throughout the document made in the mydef theorem environment.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302033/nesting-listof-to-achieve-this-appendices-list and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301545/custom-listof-not-in-content?s=6|33.7110

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: see here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151442/multiple-lists-of-theorems-with-different-titles-any-tex-in-my-case-xelatex is does what you want with just one line of `\listoftheorems`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this?

[image]

I have used the [tocloft](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/toctoft) package to create a new "table of definitions" with the commands:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listdefinitionsname}{List of definitions}
\newlistof{definitions}{dfn}{\listdefinitionsname}
```

I have then defined a new environment `defn` that will add a line to the "table of definitions"  the *first* time `\textbf{...}` is used in the environment. This is done by changing the definition of `\textbf` to be

```
  \addcontentsline{dfn}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thedefinition}#1}%
  \realtextbf{#1}%
```

inside a `defn` environment. Arguably a better way to do this would be to define a new command, say `\mydefn`, like:

```
\newcommand\mydefn[1]{\textbf{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{dfn}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thedefinition}#1}}
```

but I was trying to be faithful to the code snippets in the OP.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listdefinitionsname}{List of definitions}
\newlistof{definitions}{dfn}{\listdefinitionsname}

% create the new definition environment
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% an enhanced version of \textbf that adds an entry to list of defs
\let\realtextbf\textbf
\newcommand\answertextbf[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{dfn}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thedefinition}#1}%
  \realtextbf{#1}%
  \let\textbf\real\textbf% reset \textbf to normal
}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{defn}{o}{
  \let\textbf\answertextbf
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\definition}{\definition[#1]}
  }{\enddefinition}

\begin{document}
\listofdefinitions

\begin{defn}
\textbf{Term 1} is ...
\end{defn}

\begin{defn}[Hi]
\textbf{Term 2} is ...
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```